# how to use ngFor to an array in a collection

Tags: angular

In one of my collections in database there is an array field , 
i'm trying to use ngFor on this field and it is not working , I dont get any value between the td tags

any suggestions ?

this is my code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let supplier of components.alternativeSuppliers">
       <td>{{supplier.name}}</td>
  </tr>
```

the alternativeSuppliers is an array field in my collection

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What's the expected behavior? `supplier` must be an object. If it is, then you'll at least be able to view it's value using the `json` pipe. Here, give this a try:  `<td>{{supplier | json}}</td>`

Comment: what should be inside alternativeSuppliers?

Comment: @SiddAjmera I dont get any value between the td tags

Comment: Please share your TypeScript Component class code too. You might be fetching this data from a REST api and the data would be resolved asynchronously. Hence no data initially. You might also be getting an error on the console for the same reason.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I dont get any errors and when I tried to do it that way: *ngFor="let supplier of components" and {{supplier.alternativeSuppliers}} it's working but I get {Object Object}

Comment: I'm trying to use ngFor to a specific array field called "alternativeSuppliers" in the "components" collection , does my syntax is right ?

Comment: It's hard to tell until I know what you're getting in `alternativeSuppliers`. That's why I asked you to share your TypeScript Class Code too.

Comment: @SiddAjmera which part of it ? cause basiclly I just used a service to bring the whole collection to an array called "components" and thats it

Comment: Just share some sample response data to work with then.

Comment: @BarLevin it's because {{supplier.alternativeSuppliers}} is still an object. You need to point out what field you want to display. For example:

{{supplier.alternativeSuppliers.name}}

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting {{supplier.alternativeSuppliers}} as an [Object Object], try this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let supplier of components">
 <td>{{supplier.alternativeSuppliers.name}}</td>
</tr>
```